# How to append text to a file a 15 lines above its end

Tags: php

I am trying add HTML to a file using `fwrite()`. My final goal is to get it to add it 15 lines above the end of the file. Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php 
    $file = fopen("index.html", "r+");
    // Seek to the end
    fseek($file, SEEK_END, 0);
    // Get and save that position
    $filesize = ftell($file);
    // Seek to half the length of the file
    fseek($file, SEEK_SET, $filesize + 15);
    // Write your data
    $main = <<<MAIN
    //html goes here
    MAIN;
     fwrite($file, $main);
    // Close the file handler
    fclose($file);
?>
```

This just keeps overwriting the top of the file. 
Thanks.

Comment: How big is the file? If it is consistently huge I would not attempt it, but if it is small, it would be trivially easy to read the whole thing into an array of lines with `file()`, slice up the array accordingly, then `implode()` it back and write it out

Comment: If you want to insert HTML into an HTML document, don't do it arbitrarily, you should use a DOM parser to find the exact position you want to add it to instead.

Comment: You need to recreate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code in the question does not operate based on lines, since you're working with file size (unless there is an assumption about definition of lines in the application that is not mentioned in here). If you want to work with lines, then you'd need to search for new line characters (which separates each line with the next).

If the target file is not a large file (so we could load the whole file into memory), we could use PHP built-in `file()` to read all the lines of the file into an array, and then insert the data after the 15th element. something like this:

```
<?php
$lines = file($filename);
$num_lines = count($lines);
if ($num_lines > 15) {
    array_splice($lines, $num_lines - 15, 0, array($content));
    file_put_contents($filename, implode('', $lines));
} else {
    file_put_contents($filename, PHP_EOL . $content, FILE_APPEND);
}
```