# php seek from end and add data

Tags: php

I want to seek to line 10 from the end of the file and write some data

I tried `$file->fseek(-10, SEEK_END);` but it doesn't seek lines only bytes

```
$file = new SplFileObject('file.txt');
$file->seek(99);//this seeks to line 99 but I was wondering if there is a way to make it seek from end
$file->fwrite('hi there');
```

can someone help me out?

Comment: count lines and subtract ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to append text to a file a 15 lines above its end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26268911/how-to-append-text-to-a-file-a-15-lines-above-its-end)

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = new SplFileObject('file.txt');
$numLines = count(file('file.txt'));
$file->seek($numLines - 10);
$file->fwrite('hi there');
```

This code should get you close to what you are after. The second line counts the number of lines in the file, then this is used to find the correct value to plug into seek().

I would suggest adding checks that you don't end up passing a negative value to seek().

Ref [file() manual](http://PHP.net/file).